# Automatic syntax highlighting for Spark Python & R APIs (PySpark & SparkR)

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, tags, syntax-highlighting

Could we have the [pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pyspark) and [sparkr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sparkr) tags triggering respectively `lang-python` and `lang-r` syntax highlighting? I know that this is currently the case e.g. with [numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numpy) (triggering `lang-python`), and there is an [ongoing discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349588/we-should-set-syntax-highlighting-to-python-by-default-for-the-tensorflow-te?rq=1) to do the same for tags such as [keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/keras) and [tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tensorflow).

Comment: If these tags are only used exclusively with `Python`, they should just be tagged with `Python` from the start, which enables the appropriate highlighting. Isn't that enough?

Comment: @Carcigenicate It's not; most of the times the question has nothing to do with Python language or syntax, and it should not be tagged as `python` "automatically", as this causes unnecessary cluttering of the tag. IMHO, the choice for `numpy` was a wise one for the same reason. Anyway, it is interesting that the (identical) linked request is at +5, while this one is (currently) at -4...

Comment: @Carcigenicate taking into account the answers, too, would you tag [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48486598/how-to-predict-a-function-table-using-keras/48489086#48489086) as `python`?

Comment: I mean, it *is* a question (and answer) containing Python code. So ya, if I asked that question, I would have tagged it as Python. That's just me though. And I didn't vote on either. I just thought I'd throw in my .2 because there were votes but no comments.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Appreciated. Probably I'll open another thread focusing on this, exposing my own .2 on why I think it is not a good practice (IMHO, it has to do with *why exactly* we use tags)...

Comment: I'd like to see a discussion on that if it already hasn't been brought up. I've always tagged the language 1. For highlighting purposes and 2. Because it helps people who know those languages find the questions easier. I suppose though for niche library questions, knowledge of the language itself isn't enough to answer.

Comment: @Carcigenicate yes, that's spot on my point, plus that, at least in Python, the situation is such that we end up unnecessarily cluttering the `python` tag (w/o offering any practical advantage by doing so); anyway, I'll sum up my arguments in a new thread (and notify here) - when I find some time...

Comment: I agree with @desertnaut. The `python` tag on `pyspark` questions creates confusing among people who wants to answer and some something tend to answer in plain python and then I have to clean the mess...

Comment: @eliasah The mess is usually a result of lack of mcve, and it is not that common. And making a judgment if language tag is justified or not, requires understanding of the problem, which many posters lack. For example majority of [scala] + [apache-spark] question could be solved with OP done his/her _Scala in 24 hours_, just to understand compiler messages ;)

Comment: @desertnaut _causes unnecessary cluttering of the tag_ - I don't think it is really a concern. If you compare average views for [python] + [apache-spark] vs. [python] there is very little traffic going there. It suggests that users interested in Python in general, are already pretty effective in keeping away from niche tags.

Comment: @user8371915 yes, when you are viewing the issue *locally* from a `pyspark`-only perspective; add `numpy`, `scipy`, `pandas`, `matplotlib`, `scikit-learn`, `keras`, `tensorflow`, `pytorch` etc and the picture starts looking somewhat different...

Comment: @user8371915 interestingly enough, pault didn't bother to tag his [brilliant idea of a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48427185/how-to-make-good-reproducible-apache-spark-dataframe-examples) as `python` (despite being initially focused on `pyspark` only), hence *your* answer would be w/o syntax highlighting hadn't *I* step in to edit & add it (but it gets tiring)... :(