# Syntax highlighting auto-detection is broken for the [tensorflow] and [keras] tags

Tags: bug, syntax-highlighting

Previously code blocks on questions *tagged with a single programming language* were [automatically highlighted using that programming language](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting), unless an explicit language was specified (e.g. via code fences).

As of a few days ago this seems broken. Now even on questions with a single language tag (e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76045021/1968)) the syntax highlighting language is (mis-) auto-detected.

For instance, in the linked question (tagged as [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r), [tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tensorflow), [keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/keras)) the highlight language is incorrectly inferred as `language-bash`.

The bug is probably caused by an incorrect annotation of both [keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/keras) and [tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tensorflow) as belonging to `lang-py`. This is (a)  strictly incorrect and (b) not useful, since users of the tags are encouraged to add the relevant language tags anyway. However, IIRC the issue is not restricted to questions with those tags (unfortunately I did not save links to other questions where I noticed the issue), and the problem only started occurring recently.

Comment: *If there's more than one tag that has a highlighting language specified, it lets highlight.js infer what's the best language to use.* from https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work so in this case highlight-js does a poor job. I thought it used to be that the language hint from the most popular tag was used. Which would have helped here as lang-r in set on [tag:r].

Comment: The [[tag:r]] tag has syntax highlighting set to `lang-r` while [[tag:tensorflow]] and [[tag:keras]] have default highlighting set to `lang-py`. Thus since both have syntax hints, the question you point to doesn't use either but just decides to let the highlighter pick one.

Comment: @rene As mentioned in the question I suspect that the bug is that these non-language-specific tags have highlighting languages specified. The highlighting language should be removed from these tags.

Comment: Here is where that problem started: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349588/we-should-set-syntax-highlighting-to-python-by-default-for-the-tensorflow-te

Comment: I'm sure this has been discussed somewhere previously but in my opinion _let highlight.js infer what's the best language_ should choose **only** between the tag hint languages, if the autodetect returns something different then it should choose randomly between the hinted options.

Comment: @Marijn Yes that has been discussed years ago and has since been stuck in limbo. The syntax highlighter implementation on Stack Overflow, I’m afraid, was always half-assed and has never seen the required care. It’s actually a bit embarrassing for the one of the largest programming-related websites in the world to get syntax highlighting so badly wrong.

Comment: Are you *sure* that this *really* only started being a problem recently? We've had *many* reports of similar issues over the years since SE switched to highlight.js in 2020 (i.e., issues with highlight.js not detecting the correct syntax highlighting language when more than one language is associated with the tags). This is usually caused by having non-language tags associated with a language, which causes SE to tell highlight.js to try to auto-detect the language from all of those which are available.

Comment: Re *"It’s actually a bit embarrassing for the one of the largest programming-related websites in the world to get syntax highlighting so badly wrong."*: Indeed it is. It was very obvious from day 1 of using the new [weird syntax highlighter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353983/goodbye-prettify-hello-highlight-js-swapping-out-our-syntax-highlighter). Now nearly every post is in need of some kind of syntax highlighting hint. If syntax highlighting can't be made to work properly, it ought to be turned off by default.

Comment: @Makyen I’m well aware of these issues in general, yes. My point is that the conflict with tensorflow and keras appears to be new — how long have these been tagged for Python highlighting? the linked question is tagged as [meta-tag:status-deferred] — and obviously this is *not* a duplicate of that link: how could it possibly be? It’s a *bug report*.

Comment: @PeterMortensen highlight.js is objectively **vastly** superior to the previously employed highligher. It’s just employed *poorly*.

Comment: @Makyen Ah I just realised you retagged the other question. Never mind then. Still, I don’t understand how this can in any way be considered a duplicate (and I am *extremely* liberal with calling duplicates).